# How to apply Mix Shader to a mesh via the Weight Paint tool?

Tags: weight-painting

I was just wondering if the Weight Paint tool can be used to guide a Mix Shader through a mesh pretty much like how a ColorRamp does. So say I have BLack on Shader 1 and White on Shader 2, is there a way for the for the colors of the weight paint tool be assigned to the shaders?

I would imagine that this would be very useful in using other textures like transparency, etc.

Bright Red (Weight = 1.000) to be Shader 1 (black)

Dark Blue (Weight = 0.000) to be Shader 2 (white)

[image: Here I have a Plane subdivided via the W key and it has a subsurf modifier applied. Weight Painted the middle four vertices with a weight of 1.000]
Here I have a Plane subdivided via the W key and it has a subsurf modifier applied. Weight Painted the middle four vertices with a weight of 1.000

Comment: I don't think shader trees have access to vertex weight information, as far as I know. You should probably be using Vertex Colors Instead

Comment: oh wow. i didn't even know that there's such a thing as vertex colors :) Thank you!